# Can window.prompt() be more secure then the classic form?

Tags: javascript, security, xss, prompt

I'm developing a pure javascript app that will run entirely on the client side and **MUST BE VERY SECURE**.

At the start I need to get a password to decrypt a file, after that I don't need to save it for any future uses.

So my question is: can the `window.prompt()` be more secure to get this password than write it in a `<input>` field and retrieve it through `document.getElementById().value`?

Thanks

Comment: When you say "more secure"... Are you trying to hide that password input? & Hide it from whom? Browser extensions... Other folks who might use the same computer...? Are you trying to disable the browser's built-in feature to save & autofill the password?

Comment: @Reed I want to hide it form script injections for example. I pass the password directly to the function such as `decrypt(prompt('Write the password:'))`. After that it is no longer possible to access the password, isn't it?

Comment: I just hope, you do understand that the way you're planing to do this, is the exact same way every injection will intercept this data. This adds literally nothing in regards of security.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no guarantee of practical difference in security. An injected script could hook window.prompt to intercept anything entered. For example:

```js
// In the attacker's script
const _prompt = window.prompt;
window.prompt = function(p) {
  const v = _prompt(p);
  alert(`I intercepted ${v}`);
  return v;
}

// In your script
window.prompt("Enter your secret password");
```

You could perhaps take a private handle to window.prompt, but you'd have to be *certain* that it happened prior to point that a script could be injected.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you very much!  ;)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no difference as you don't seem to send the form over the network and there is no extra level of security between window.prompt and the browser (where you have to handle the entered password at some time).

As for any other vulnerabilities such as keyloggers, infected packages, weak or wrongly stored passwords, there are very much open to the same risks.

Don't know if I'd use the term VERY SECURE in regards to any javascript application, but well, there you have it.

**Edit: Actually, there is one major difference. I don't think there is a way to mask the entry in the window.prompt like you can do with a form input set to type password. If there is no workaround for that, and I don't think there is, given everything else is about the same level of security, the input field is definetly more secure.**

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt

```html
<button onClick="window.prompt()">trigger prompt</button>

<input type='password'>
```

Comment: I thought this: with a script injection can be possible to retrieve the password wrote in an INPUT field but this cannot be possible if I use prompt(). Does that make sense?

Comment: No, it doesn't, because after the user enters the password in the window.prompt you'll have to handle it at the same level as the input field: within the browser. There is no extra level of security in between those two afaik.